# Linking my dropzone files with my users table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dropzone.js

So after like changing my code for more than 100 times, I finally got dropzone to work properly.

Now the issue is that I have a listing table and a Photos table.
There will be a form where the users would be creating a listing and inside that form there will be a dropzone to drop your images.

What i want here is that somehow I should be able to associate those images with my current listing.

So the problem with dropzone is that the moment you drop an image it hits the post action and inserts an entry in the database and since by that time the listing form submit button is not yet hit,I do not have any listing id to create an association between images and the listing.

One way I can solve this is by setting

```
autoProcessQueue:false
```

and then on submit set it to true.

But even then it's not working.

can someone please help me.

I am using carrierwave with cloudinary for file uploads and dropzone.js for the fancy UI.

Here are all the codes:
/*new.html.erb*/

```
<%=form_for @listing, :html=> { class:'ui form centered black segment'} do |f|%>

   <div class="required field">
     <label>Title</label>  
     <%=f.text_field :title,placeholder:'Title of the listing'%>
   </div>

   <div class="field ui segment dropzone dropzone-previews" id='my-dropzone'>
     <p class="dz-message">You can drop an image here or click to upload."
     </p>
   </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
   Dropzone.autoDiscover=false;
   var myDropzone=new Dropzone("#my-dropzone",
   {
     autoProcessQueue:false,
     url:'/listings',
     paramName:"file",
     addRemoveLinks:true,
     previewsContainer:'.dropzone-previews',
     headers: 
     {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
     }


    });
    $('.ui.submit').click(function(e){

       myDropzone.autoProcessQueue();
    });
    </script>

 <%end%>
```

Inside my listing controller, I am trying to do something like this.
This is what i tried to get this working, but i need someone to suggest me a better way to do this,

/*Listing controller*/

```
def create
        @listing=Listing.create(listing_params)
        @photo=@listing.photos.create(file_name: params[:file])
        redirect_to root_url
end
```

Even this aint working for any images upload, it set the listing id though but the image file name is still empty.

/*Listing.rb*/

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :photos
end
```

/*Photo.rb*/

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :file_name, PhotoUploader
    belongs_to :listing
end

/*------------------Photos schema---------------------*/
id   |    file_name  |  listing_id
```

What should I do to create some sort of linking between the uploaded images and the listings.

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer -- but you need to pass the listing.id from rails to the javascript post request and then back to rails to assign to listing_id (e.g., by changing the post url from 'listings' to 'listings/id_number'). Will try to give better info later if this doesn't help.

Comment: But first check in your rails controller to see if listing_id is already being passed in with the post request -- if it is, you just need to add something like `@photo.listing_id = params[:listing_id]` then `@photo.save`.

Comment: Joseph,If I try your method,what will happen if I upload multiple images.In that case will multiple listings be created,coz thats not what I want.Because one listing can have a maximum of 4 images associated with it.So in this scenario,listing table will have one entry and photos table will have 4 entries with the same listing id.Will that be possible with the current code.

Comment: Yeah, I see that. Sorry I only had a few minutes to comment earlier and didn't think through the whole workflow. Looks like you got a good answer below, though! You could also edit the create method to check first if a listing exists and only create a new one if it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you can save the listing using remote form which will submit the form using ajax instead of the normal mechanism. In the create action after listing gets saved store the id in a session variable. In create.js.erb where it will be handling you can process the photo using myDropzone.processQueue() function. When photo gets processed in controller action bind it to the listing from session variable and save it.

```
class ListingsController < ApplicationController 
  def create
    @listing = Listing.new(listing_params)
    if @listing.save
      session[:listing] = @listing.id
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  def media
    @listing = Listing.find(session[:listing])
    @media = Media.new(file_name: params[:file], listing: @listing)
    if @media.save!
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json{ render :json => @media }
      end
    end
   end
 end
```

Create Dropzone programmatically using javascript and then reference the variable in create.js.erb

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   Dropzone.options.mediaDropzone = false;
   mediaDropzone = new Dropzone('div#media-dropzone', { 
     url: "/listings/media",
     autoProcessQueue: false
   });

   mediaDropzone.on("success", function(file, responseText) {
     console.log(responseText.file_name.url);
     console.log(responseText);
   });
 });
```

In create.js.erb

```
 mediaDropzone.processQueue();
```

To make it short we save the listing and in the callback we save the photo and relate the two.

You can check the example in the formsubmit branch of the repo here https://github.com/sudharti/dropzone-rails-demo/tree/formsubmit

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for.Worked perfectly for me.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't create a table for the users, a table for the images and for each user saved, you create a relationship! So that each user has many images. You can uses has_many and beglons_to.  Sorry for any grammar mistake, my native language is portuguese.

```
table users
id | name
1  | Josh
2  | Pedro

table images
id | user_id
1  | 1
2  | 1
3  | 1
4  | 2
```